# C# How to serialize an object in different ways

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

Let's say I have a class that I want to to be able to serialize that looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Var1 {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Var2 {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Var3 {get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes I want it to be serialized with Var3 omited, so basically like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Var1 {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Var2 {get; set; }

    public object Var3 {get; set; }
}
```

and in other cases I want it with Var2 omited.

Is there any way of decorating the class with attributes that will enable me to choose in what way i want this class serialized?

Comment: Try using ViewModels

Comment: see like, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21091785/1271037

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10528967/1271037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `EmitDefaultValue` parameter to attribute.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Var1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object Var2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object Var3 { get; set; }
}
```

When you want omit `Var2`, set it to `null`.

```
SomeClass sc = ...;
sc.Var2 = null;
```

In result it will be omitted.

Comment: This is something that might actually work in my case. I wil try it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSON.NET for serialization you can use [Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)

> To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns
>   boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method
>   name with ShouldSerialize. The result of the method determines whether
>   the property is serialized. If the method returns true then the
>   property will be serialized, if it returns false then the property
>   will be skipped.

Example

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Var1 {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Var2 {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Var3 {get; set; }

    public bool SerializeVar2 {get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeVar2
    {
        return SerializeVar2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately using Json.NET is not an option for me

Comment: So what serializer? Beceuse solution depends on serializer, there is no one universal way.